# addons not showing up

Tags: add-on

I'm not very tech savy, but I want to get into modeling. So I watched some tutorials, and finally decided to get some addons. I downloaded one, but couldn't find it until I extracted it (which I should not have done). Now I can't find the file, the only program for files I have is file explorer (any recommendations?) so what I could do was limited. Now the addon won't show. Images below show my file explorer page (what  should i do next?), and what I get when I extract it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How did you install the addon? Did you use the Install from file option? Also looking at your screenshot the testing addons are not enabled for display. So, if your addon is under that category it will not be displayed.

Comment: I used the install from file option ,however it was 7 files instead of the one that was in the video , I also checked all tabs now and it's still not there

Comment: How about installing the addon from the compressed file!! Looks like you extracted the files.

Comment: the reason i extracted it was because otherwise it wouldnt show up , let me try again

Comment: i have 8zip opening the file , now what do i do ?

Comment: It seems to want to extract the file immediately

Comment: Do not extract the file. Save the compressed file after downloading and then use the install file button to open it.

Comment: What program should I use to do this ?file explorer isn't working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To install this add-on you don't need to unzip the folder.

Go to the Add-ons tab in user preferences and navigate to your add-on zip location and double click on it, then once it is installed make sure to tick the checkbox to activate it.

Steps:

1. Download Zip Folder
   [image]
2. Go to File -> User Preferences
   [image]
3. Then choose install from file
   [image]
4. Navigate to the downloaded add-on zip or simple copy the path of the zip folder and paste it in the path text box as shown below then select the zip folder and click on the install from file button
   [image: 5. Enable the add-on by checking the] checkbox
   [image]
   [image]
5. Select your Object then in the Tools Menu you will find a new tab called `Sculpt` click on it[image]

Comment: ummm how exactly do i do that , sorry im not really that used to this ai , just know the basics

Comment: @user39827 can you share the zip folder and I'll show you how step to step?

Comment: this  https://github.com/MadMinstrel/blender-sculpt-tools

Comment: @user39827 answer updated with step by step screenshot. Don't forget to tick and mark the answer as resolved to help future users having the same issue as shown here https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRRKZ.png

Comment: ive got all but 4 ,sorry if this is troublesome but , its not there , i only have a .master , no zip , and when i install it nothing happens

Comment: @user39827 in 4 you navigate to the location where the add-on zip folder was dowloaded, you are the only one who knows this location, where did you download the add-on zip folder? If you have the path then simply paste it in the text box. Answer updated point 4

Comment: Wish I could do more,thx,had uninstall all my old files then reinstall em

Answer (score 2):

sometimes blender will break the files of addon in addon folder. so you can not see it on blender addon list.

What you only need to do is install them manually. 
Just unzip your addon
make sure all the addon file in one folder
copy this folder into this folder 
C:\Users{user name}\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.81\scripts\addons\

restart your blender and then you can see your addon on the list.

Comment: Note the path is for windows only.

Answer (score 1):

The way to activate an Add-on is by checking the box located on the left of the add-on name. Then you can close the user preferences window.

If you want the add-on to be enabled permanently then enable it and press "Save User Settings".
[image]

Comment: im trying to install  sculpting tools ,but the addon i installed wont show up ,

Comment: I'm trying to follow the video , introductions sculpting with blender

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION**---------------------------------------------------------------------

IF you Go to Roaming/blender foundation/blender/2.xx/scripts/addons ,you will find your installed addons on that version

*If some addons arent showing up, Then go to addons folder and modify somethings of that specific addon's file*

1. **make sure that if you open your specific addon's folder, you should directly reach to .py files.
   i mean , there should not be any extra folders between that path**
2. make sure that there aren't any dots(.), and some symbols like that

**THIS WORKS Mostly**

Comment: Worth noting the folder mentioned is for windows. If you go to the python console and type in the command `bpy.utils.script_paths("addons")` it will display a list of folders where blender looks for addons. One will be your user folder, where you install your custom addons, one will be the addons folder that is distributed with blender.