# Export Paper Model add-on will not install on Bender 2.79b

Tags: export

I installed Blender 2.79b on Windows 10. I downloaded the add on script from:

https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.79/Add-ons
https://archive.blender.org/wiki/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/Paper_Model/

When I install the Add-on from file through User Preferences, the io_export_paper_model.py file gets installed in the user's AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\addons folder.

However when I go to File -> Export, the Export Paper Model option does not appear.

Am I missing a step?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [addons not showing up](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80670/addons-not-showing-up)

Comment: did you enable the addon after installing?