# Installing an add-on from zip does not show up in Edit > Preferences > Add-ons

Tags: add-on

following advice posted elsewhere ([SO thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80670/addons-not-showing-up), [Ducky 3D tutorial](https://youtu.be/fK9Umxy1AAs?t=82)) I followed these steps to install the [Bizualizer](https://github.com/doakey3/Bizualizer) addon:

1. Downloaded the repo
2. zipped the repo
3. located the .zip file in Edit > Preferences > Add-ons > Install...
4. the add-on does not show up in the search.

I decided instead to try and install the add-on by moving the downloaded repo (not the zip) into the [User-Defined Add-on Path](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/preferences/addons.html#installing-add-ons) and it was indeed detected but gave me the following error when I tried enabling it:
[image: A traceback indicating a ModuleNotFoundError saying that there is no module named Bizualizer]

Does this mean that it was failing before because of an error in the module? If I put the .zip into my user-defined add-on path it simply is not detected, but putting the folder there lets it be detected but then Blender claims that there is a module not found error.

Comment: what version of Blender are you using? 3.5.1? I don't use this addon but it says in the repository that it is for 2.80 so maybe it is not supposed to work on 3.5?

Comment: @MikoCG ah, that could be it, thank you. I am currently on 3.5.1

Comment: Hm, thats not it I tried to install [this addon](https://blendermarket.com/products/audvis) which claims to work for Blender 3.5, and I am receiving the same error

Comment: It's a third-party addon, not part of Blender so you should ask the author.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here has been resolved by updating Python, I was on python 310, updated to 311 and it works now.

Comment: Thanks for your self-answer. After a little while you'll be able to accept it (with the tick,) marking it solved, for us.